# How to Format Jsx back too what it used to be

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My jsx looks like this:

```
 div className = "App" >
        <
        Navbar / >
        <
        main className = "main-content position-relative max-height-vh-100 h-100 mt-1 border-radius-lg " >

        {
            /* nav show */ } <
        nav className = "navbar navbar-main navbar-expand-lg px-0 mx-4 shadow-none border-radius-xl"
        id = "navbarBlur"
        navbar - scroll = "true" >
        <
        div className = "container-fluid py-1 px-3" >
        <
        nav aria - label = "breadcrumb" >
        <
        ol className = "breadcrumb bg-transparent mb-0 pb-0 pt-1 px-0 me-sm-6 me-5" >
        <
        li className = "breadcrumb-item text-sm" >
        <
        a className = "opacity-5 text-dark"
        href = "javascript:;" >
        Pages <
        /a> < /
```

I've uninstalled all formatters. I'm using vscode. How do I get back to normal code? All online formatters don't work.

Comment: Ctrl + Z doesnt work?

Comment: Is the file a `.js` or `.jsx`? Really should avoid `.js`, it's harder for tools to detect that's what you're using. It's also not valid JS, so it shouldn't be in a `.js` file. That's probably your issue.

Answer (score 1):

##### 1. Install Prettier

here is the link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

##### 2. Set the formatter

Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and select `Format Document With...`. And then select *Prettier*.

[image]

##### 3. Change the language mode

At the bottom change, the format to **Javascript React**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add this line to your vscode:

```
setting.json    
{
 "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```